# Change DateTime format using web.config in dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have used

```
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="en-IN" uiCulture="en-US"  />
```

Need DateTime format like **13-06-2020 10.55 AM** but getting only 13-06-2020 10.55. AM is missing from culture="en-IN" uiCulture="en-US"

Comment: How you get `13-06-2020 10.55`, show us your code

Comment: Try <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US